# Bit of SQL Code that I'm not getting

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I've got this bit of code from another SQL person who left the company. I can't seem to figure out exactly what is trying to be done in this section of the query, it is also throwing and error at `= LEFT(period,4)=1)` among other points

```
and (
   case when (
          case when (substring(FlowchartName,1,5)='HEDIS') 
               then SUBSTRING(FlowchartName,7,4)
               else cast(20 as varchar(4)) + substring(FlowchartName,2,2)
          end = LEFT(period,4)
        ) then 
            case when RIGHT(period,2) in (1,2,3,4,5,6) 
                 then 
                    case when ReportingType='RETROSPECTIVE' 
                         then 1
                         else 0
                    end
                 else 0
            end
        when (
           case when substring(FlowchartName,1,5)='HEDIS' 
                then SUBSTRING(FlowchartName,7,4)
                else cast(20 as varchar(4)) + substring(FlowchartName,2,2)
           end
        ) = LEFT(period,4)=1
    ) then 
         case when RIGHT(period,2) in (10,11,12) 
              then 
                 case when ReportingType='PROSPECTIVE' 
                      then 1
                      else 0
                 end
              else 0
         end
      else 0
end ) = 1
)
```

Comment: First of all format this code. Machine can understand wall of text, human not always.

Comment: After formating it there are undoubtedly missing code here

Comment: The two final close parentesis are lost in this code, there is no plece for then unless you didn't past all code.

Answer (score 0):

- It first tests to see if the year in question for a particular `[FlowchartName]` is the same as the year in `[period]` (it looks to assume years can only be from 2000 onwards)
- It looks to be further testing the last two digits of the year in question for a particular `[FlowchartName]`
- It uses this in an attempting to allow query results to be returned/joined on (you haven't provided the context) based on whether the results are `'RETROSPECTIVE'`, or `'PROSPECTIVE'`
- `'RETROSPECTIVE'` results are returned when the last two digits of the year are 1 through 6 (I wouldn't be surprised if this test fails anyway seeing as it is only providing 1 character strings to test against a 2 character string) and the column `[ReportingType]='RETROSPECTIVE'`. I believe the intent here was `'RETROSPECTIVE'` pertains to the years 2001, or 2002, or 2003, or 2004, or 2005, or 2006
- `'PROSPECTIVE'` results are returned in the same manner as for `'RETROSPECTIVE'`, the slight difference being the column `[ReportingType]` needs to have a value of `'PROSPECTIVE'` and the year needs to be 2010, or 2011, or 2012

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Much appreciated. It throws an error at the point where = LEFT(period,4)=1) then case when RIGHT(period,2) in "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 102
Incorrect syntax near '='."